# android: Variable passed for R.drawable.variableValue

Tags: android

```
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

this line is working good for me

can I pass a variable value instead of icon
like if i have 10 images in drawable and i want to decide on runtime which image to show
can i pass the value through a variable and work it like

```
    String variableValue = imageName;
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.variableValue);
```

Answer (score 22):

Resources.getIdentifier() can solve your problem.

```
String variableValue = imageName;
iv.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(variableValue, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use an array to define your drawables:

```
int[] images = new int[2];
images[0] = R.drawables.image1;
images[1] = R.drawables.image2;
```

And then you can use this array to set a image at runtime:

```
lv.setImageResource(images[i]);
```

Where is is in this case either 0 to point to the first image or 1 to point to the second image of the array.

Comment: worked like charm ... awsome :) ... 

Thank you for making life easier rather bringing more complications into something which is already complicated(atleast for me).

Comment: By me it works only with R.drawable instead of R.drawables

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work that way.

In your first line `icon` is a generated `static final` member of the `static final class R.drawable` so trying to concatenate it up like it was a `String` would give you a compiler error.

But you could try using

```
iv.setImageURI(uri);
```

where `uri` is the URI to your image, so you can use a string value here.
Also, according to the api documentation, it would be a better solution to use `setImageBitmap`: you should consider it based on your resources.

**APIDocs:**

```
public void setImageURI (Uri uri)
```

**Since: API Level 1**

> Sets the content of this ImageView to
>   the specified Uri.
>
> This does Bitmap reading and decoding
>   on the UI thread, which can cause a
>   latency hiccup. If that's a concern,
>   consider using
>   setImageDrawable(Drawable) or
>   setImageBitmap(Bitmap) and
>   BitmapFactory instead.

**Parameters**
`uri`  The Uri of an image